# Is is possible to use JQGrid for sorting remotely?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I tried using:

```
$('#Table').jqGrid('setGridParam', { sortname: mycol });
$('#Table').jqGrid('setGridParam', { sortorder: myorder });
$('#Table').jqGrid('sortGrid', mycol)
```

the grid doesn't do anything. My data is in remote server, and I sort it remotely (using the DB server once the correct column and order sequence is pushed via ajax. I basically want to be able to sort the grid programmatically once the correct grid settings have been loaded, those settings store for each column: (1)position, (2)size, (3)status(show/hide), (4)sorting status. So far I've been able to store/retrieve and apply (once retrieved) for 1, 2, and 3. But I am having a hard time applying those (I can store/retrieve it as json objects the sortname and sortorder) into/from the DB. By the way if you click on any column it does the sorting (sends the right request to the DB) and shows the right icon (ASC>DESC>UNSORTED.....) in sequence after each click and shows the right data.

The closest I have it to the solution is this:

```
$('#TableData').jqGrid('setGridParam', { sortname: mysortname, sortorder: myortorder });
$('#TableData').trigger('reloadGrid');
```

The actual data gets loaded onto the grid, the right query is sent to the DB server: 'order by col1 asc, col2 desc, col3 asc, ... coln ordern'

The problem is the sorting icons, I use this function to set it right before calling 'reloadGrid':

```
var setSortingIcon = function (colName, sortOrder) {
    var $self = $(this),
        colModel = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel"),
        cmLength = colModel.length,
        cm,
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < cmLength; i++) {
        cm = colModel[i];
        if (cm.name === colName) {
            var icons = $($self[0].grid.headers[i].el).find('>div.ui-jqgrid-sortable>span.s-ico');
            if (sortOrder === 'asc') { // this.p.sortorder doesn't work!
                icons.find('>span.ui-icon-asc').show();
                icons.find('>span.ui-icon-asc')[0].style.display = '';
                icons.find('>span.ui-icon-desc').hide();
            }
            else if (sortOrder === 'desc') {
                icons.find('>span.ui-icon-desc').show();
                icons.find('>span.ui-icon-desc')[0].style.display = '';
                icons.find('>span.ui-icon-asc').hide();
            }

            else {
                icons.find('>span.ui-icon-desc').hide();
                icons.find('>span.ui-icon-asc').hide();
            }
            // no need to proceed
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

It works for setting the column to not sorted (clearing the pyramid icon by sending an empty string as sortOrder), but for some of ASC, DESC, it shows the incorrect icon on the column, e.g. for an ASC order which is a bold pyramid, it might give me any combination of: a lighted (not bold) pyramid, a lighted normal inverted pyramid (DESC), a bold normal inverted pyramid (DESC).

I also tried to use this function that I got from some other post:

```
   var setSorting = function (colName, sortOrder) {
        var $self = $(this),
            colModel = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel"),
            headers = $self[0].grid.headers,
            showSortIconsInAllCols = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "viewsortcols")[0],
            cmLength = colModel.length,
            cm,
            $sortSpan,
            i;
        for (i = 0; i < cmLength; i++) {
            cm = colModel[i];
            if (cm.name === colName) {
                cm.lso = String(sortOrder).toLowerCase() === "desc" ? "desc" : "asc";
            }
            $sortSpan = $(headers[i].el).find(">div.ui-jqgrid-sortable>span.s-ico");
            if (showSortIconsInAllCols || cm.lso) {
                $sortSpan.show();
                if (cm.lso) {
                    $sortSpan.find(">span.ui-icon-" + cm.lso)
                        .removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Doesn't do the job either. Again so far the data is nice. I'd like to change the icons successfully. The reason I decided to go with sortGrid at the beginning of this post is because it does the icon things for you (so it says) or may be sortGrid is not the way to go. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's very important to include the information about the version of jqGrid, which you used and about the fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). I develop free jqGrid fork and implemented `threeStateSort: true` option (try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/3stateSort.htm)). Moreover there are exist `multiSort: true` option since a long time. It uses 3-state by default. Both options work for local and remote sorting. Do you tried to use the options? Is it what you need?